# How to parse URL # fragments with query items in Swift

Tags: swift, parsing, url, oauth

Query parameters sometimes get passed as URL fragments instead of query parameters - e.g. during OAuth flows to provide client-only access to parameters.

What's the simplest way to parse a URL like:

- `https://example.com/auth-callback#access_token=mytoken&expires_in=36000&scope=zap+profile`

into key values for:

- access_token, expires_in, scope

Answer (score 15):

Simply pass the fragment property as a query string to a new URLComponent and read the parsed query objects:

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/auth-callback#access_token=mytoken&expires_in=36000&scope=zap+profile")

var components = URLComponents()
components.query = url.fragment

for item in components.queryItems! {
  print("\(item.name): \(item.value)")
}
```